# Freemarker Template Data Binding in jbpm

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2, freemarker, jbpm

I am writing my task-forms of `JBPM5.4` in freemarker. My question is that it would be possible that pojos are initialized on the server side when html form is submitted like facility available in `struts`. I have integrated JBPM with my application written in `Spring 3` using REST API.

please give me proper direction as soon as possible...

Comment: Too localized, try to remove the red-herring tags and aspects of the problem (jbpm and struts2).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but you could for example have your task form return basic data types and do the initialization of the POJOs in your process itself (for example using an on-exit script on your user task).

Comment: thanks...right now I'm doing same thing... I mean that I want model driven application like in Struts2 [link](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-modeldriven-example/)...Is it possible same thing in jbpm5?